# How can we use Microsoft Enterprise library to send email in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can we use Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0 to send emails in asp.net?

I am looking at some stuff in C# or VB.net where I can use Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0 for my application.

I want to send emails to developers if any exception arises in the code during development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I can also achieve my task through microsoft enterprise library**

**Steps

1. Add microsoft enterprise library 5.0 dll to you bin folder and you below web.config file
   **

**Use code for testing**

```
try
        {
            
            throw new NullReferenceException("General null reference");
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogEntry logEntry = new LogEntry();
            logEntry.EventId = 100;
            logEntry.Priority = 2;
            logEntry.Message = "Informational message";
            Logger.Write(ex.ToString() + logEntry);
        }
```

**Web.config file**

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true"/>
  </configSections>
  <loggingConfiguration name="" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Email Trace Listener"
           type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.EmailTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
           listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.EmailTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
           toAddress="xyz@gmail.com" fromAddress="abc@gmail.com" subjectLineStarter="Exception Occured" smtpServer="smtp.gmail.com" smtpPort="587"
           formatter="Text Formatter" authenticationMode="UserNameAndPassword" useSSL="true" userName="abc@gmail.com" password="********"/>
      <add name="Flat File Trace Listener"
           type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
           listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
           fileName="trace.log"/>
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
      <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
           template="Timestamp: {timestamp}{newline}&#xA;Message: {message}{newline}&#xA;Category: {category}{newline}&#xA;Priority: {priority}{newline}&#xA;EventId: {eventid}{newline}&#xA;Severity: {severity}{newline}&#xA;Title:{title}{newline}&#xA;Machine: {localMachine}{newline}&#xA;App Domain: {localAppDomain}{newline}&#xA;ProcessId: {localProcessId}{newline}&#xA;Process Name: {localProcessName}{newline}&#xA;Thread Name: {threadName}{newline}&#xA;Win32 ThreadId:{win32ThreadId}{newline}&#xA;Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}{newline})}" name="Text Formatter"/>
    </formatters>
    <categorySources>
      <add switchValue="All" name="General">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Flat File Trace Listener"/>
          <add name="Email Trace Listener"/>
        </listeners>
      </add>
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
      <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events"/>
      <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category"/>
      <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Flat File Trace Listener"/>
          <add name="Email Trace Listener"/>
        </listeners>
      </errors>
    </specialSources>
  </loggingConfiguration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of using the Logging Application Block to log an error to an email in this blog post.

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1325/how-to-use-logging-application-block-in-enterprise-library-50

Answer (score 0):

**I have figure out the solution for achieving my task Logging error as email. I have used ELMAH: Error Logging Modules and Handlers.**

**Steps to configure**
1) Download Elmah.dll, copy the elmah.dll inside you bin folder
2) Use below web.config file. And that's it.

Whenever any exception arises in you code an email will be sent to the respected person.

**Web.Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
      <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
      <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings/>
  <!--<connectionStrings>
        <add name="elmah-sql" connectionString="Data Source=***;Initial Catalog=***;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=***;Password=***" />
    </connectionStrings>-->
  <elmah>
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="elmah-sql"/>
    <errorMail from="xyz@gmail.com" to="abc@example.com" subject="Error" smtpServer="smtp.gmail.com" smtpPort="587" userName="xyz@gmail.com" password="***********" useSsl="true" async="true"/>
  </elmah>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="CustomError.aspx">
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="NotAuthorized.aspx"/>
      <!--<error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />-->
    </customErrors>
    <httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
      <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah"/>
    </httpModules>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```